# Toast is undentified

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've got the information to display posts/categories depending on API results. When there's nothing to display, I want to toast a warning message.

I have following code

```
  async asyncData({ $axios, route, app}) {
    const [blogPost, blogCategoryPosts] = await Promise.all([
        $axios.get(`${process.env.API_DOMAIN}/api/blog/posts${route.path}`).then(response => response.data).catch(error => {}),
        $axios.get(`${process.env.API_DOMAIN}/api/blog/categories${route.path}`).then(response => response.data).catch(error => {}),
    ])

        if(blogPost == undefined && blogCategoryPosts == undefined) {
          this.toast.error('Error')

    }

    return {
      blogPost: blogPost,
      blogCategoryPosts: blogCategoryPosts,
      locale: app.i18n.locale
    }
  },
```

But it responds with `Cannot read property 'toast' of undefined` , why is that? I have `@nuxtjs/toast` enabled in my project and it works well elsewhere.

Just have added following code to same page and it worked:

```
    mounted() {
    // This works
    this.$toast.error('Error')
  }
```

Not sure how to use it with async though.

Comment: Does `.catch(error => {})` tell you if an error was encountered, and what that error was?

Comment: nope, no errors

Comment: Or does it hide the errors from you with `error => {}`? Try removing that and see if it tells you what it wrong. ICBW, but to me it looks like that bit of code tells it to ignore errors, and you say the same code works elsewhere.

Comment: ah, then it prints out 404 message. Also, i've tried to remove everything but keep ```this.toast.error('Error')``` inside async function but it still tells that toast is undefined.

Comment: And why would it give a 404 message?

Comment: axios get that response from the API.

Comment: What is the URL which gives a 404 response? Can you fix your code to use a valid URL?

Comment: It's all in development stage on local network, sadly can't share the link. If I'm going directly to to the API address it displays 404 - so everything is okay on API side.

Comment: Shall I if answer isn't about that? It's uncovers only in comments. I've asked @Nima Ebrazeh to make new answer. Nvm, just noticed he edited it :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should write `app.toast` instead of `this.toast` because `this` keyword is not available in `asyncData`.

but if `app.toast` does not work please try `app.$toast` too.

**Updated Answer:**

Right now I realized that $toast even not working in created lifecycle hook. This is because it's a client-side module and it is impossible to display toast on the server-side. For further details I recommend see [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2845) in github.

You can return for example an `error` variable from `asyncData` which is true if request failed. Then check in `mounted` lifecycle hook and if the value of error is set to true, then show the toast.

Comment: yeah I've tried both of them before but it just returns another error then ```Cannot read property 'error' of undefined ```

Comment: Right now I realized that $toast even not working in created lifecycle hook. This is because it's a client-side module and it is impossible to display toast on the server-side. For further details I recommend see [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2845) in github.

Comment: So I guess call some method from async should do the trick.

Comment: No you cannot use this trick because it's still running in asyncData!

Comment: You can return for example an `error` variable from asyncData which is true if request failed. Then check in `mounted` lifecycle and if the value of error is set true, show the toast.

Comment: Yeah I realized then that is still async and won't help at all. Thanks, I definitely will do something in this way.

Comment: @NimaEbrazeh You should post your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69154107/toast-is-undentified#comment122225951_69154187) as the answer so that it could help others with the same problem :)

Comment: indeed, I just have added ```return { error: 'err'}``` into ```if``` statement of async function and into mounted ```if(this.error)``` everything works like a charm now.